# How to explain the concept of Basically Money (this site) to others?

Tags: site-information

Visiting Basically Money daily, I am simply enamored by it all. Sadly, most of my colleagues don't know about the site, let alone the [trilogy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/).

- How do I explain to them the concept
  of the site?

Comment: Pandiya: Thanks for sharing your enthusiasm! :-) I've made this question a community wiki and tagged it "meta" (i.e. about this site). I also added a link to the "trilogy" - there may be a few non-developer / non-IT people here who wouldn't otherwise catch the reference.  :-)

Comment: I thought it was a Lord of the Rings reference :-)

Comment: @chris we people here in india are waiting for the complete release of basicallymoney.com

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to explain the site to others, I agree.  What I've done is posted questions on behalf of people when they've come up in conversation, to illustrate the benefit of a community of people answering your question (rather than you out searching the Net for the answer)... turning it into repository of answers in which the best answer is voted to the top.  Brilliant concept.

Comment: That i definatley a great way to put it!  Another thing to say is that it's just people helping people and sharing their knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

With reputation based collaborative editing of both questions and answers, the stack exchange powered sites allow a community to not only safely find the best answer to a question, but to make that question easy to find on the Internet.

We can (based on earned community trust) edit and maintain all aspects of this site so even as answers change over time, so too can the answers and questions reflect that change.  You can count on a stack exchange site like basicallymoney.com to be up to date and relevant even on questions ask years ago.

It is also a good place to learn about the funny word Canadians and Brits have for normal everyday stuff.**

Comment: **I kid, I kid...

Comment: Like, did you know that Canadians drink milk out a bag?  What up with that?

Comment: Okay - so what do Americans use for containers of milk larger than 2L (2 quarts)?

Comment: Big recyclable plastic jugs:  http://www.amazon.com/Tuscan-Whole-Milk-Gallon-128/dp/B00032G1S0/

Comment: In the UK we just keep cows in the fridge

Comment: Seems like direct cow would save money, but your mitten and scarf costs must be higher.

Comment: I think we might be milking this a bit much

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the learning curve can be steep for someone who did not use stackoverflow.com before. The best approach to explain this would be to sit down with your colleagues and show them and help them to get started.